# Can I remove unneeded 2 plugs from PCI-E power cable?

Tags: power, pcie

I have a PCI-E PSU power cable and I have two unneeded pins at the end (only need 6 power pins but have 6+2). Can I simply remove the pin where these two wires enter the PSU?

[image: Imgur]

I wouldn't think that this would cause any problems, but better safe than sorry :) The two-wire connector on the right is wired to a single pin in the upper-right corner of the grey connector at left.

Also, how do I get the pins out of the casings? They seem to be pretty attached.

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the unneeded connector and conductors. However, in the event that you end up needing an 8 Pin PCI cable in the future, you may regret it. You may also damage the connector in the process.

Pins are spring loaded and the usual process for removing them is to use a proper size pin extractor. Inserted from the pin side, the extractor consists of a sleeve which slides over the pin and folds the locking wings back into the pin. A plunger on the tool is then pressed which goes through the center of the pin and pushes it back out of the housing. These extractors come in different sizes and are about $10 or so.

In this case I really think you are better off leaving the cable assembly as is.

Comment: +1 - "In this case I really think you are better off leaving the cable assembly as is." --- Totally Agree.

Comment: Since I'm going to be sleeving these wires anyway (meaning I'll have to remove the pins), I might as well buy the pin extractor and leave these out when I'm finished sleeving.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Molex]
This is what the molex pins look like. You can see the little tabs on the side. This prevent you from pulling the pin out of the cable from the back/wired side. You can use a tiny screw driver to push them in enough to pull them out (push the wire in first to give the tabs slack).

But since these are soldered on, if you want to get rid of them, you are better off cutting them off from the connector and adding some heatshrink to isolate them.